# Displaying different images with actual size in matplotlib subplot

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I'm working on some image processing algorithms using python and matplotlib.  I'd like to display the original image and the output image in a figure using a subplot (e.g. the original image next to the output image).  The output image(s) are of different size than the original image.  I'd like to have the subplot display the images in their actual size (or uniformly scaled) so that I can compare "apples to apples".  I currently use:

```
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.imshow(originalImage)
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.imshow(outputImage)
plt.show()
```

The result is that I get the subplot, but both images are scaled so that they are the same size (despite the fact that the axes on the output image are different than the axes of the input image).  Just to be explicit: if the input image is 512x512 and the output image is 1024x1024 then both images are displayed as though they are the same size.

Is there a way to force matplotlib to either display the images at their respective actual sizes (preferable solution so that matplotlib's dynamic rescaling doesn't effect the displayed image) or to scale the images such that they are displayed with sizes proportional to their actual sizes?

Comment: I think `figimage` may be useful to you ... this question possibly a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960755/how-to-set-imshow-scale) question...

Comment: Thank you.  I will check it out.  Yes looks like a duplicateish post.  Guess I didn't see that one when searching.  Thanks!

Comment: use `sharex` and `sharey` to share axes. See my answer below

Answer (score 22):

This is the answer that you are looking for:

```
def display_image_in_actual_size(im_path):

    dpi = 80
    im_data = plt.imread(im_path)
    height, width, depth = im_data.shape

    # What size does the figure need to be in inches to fit the image?
    figsize = width / float(dpi), height / float(dpi)

    # Create a figure of the right size with one axes that takes up the full figure
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
    ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])

    # Hide spines, ticks, etc.
    ax.axis('off')

    # Display the image.
    ax.imshow(im_data, cmap='gray')

    plt.show()

display_image_in_actual_size("./your_image.jpg")
```

Adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34768717/matplotlib-unable-to-save-image-in-same-resolution-as-original-image/34769840).

Comment: The question asked for the case of displaying two images side-by-side in one figure.

Comment: Please read the question again. It says "different **images**". Yor code uses a **single** image.. Which is OK but not what the question asks. I see 22 upvotes eheras your answer should be instead **downvoted** (which I didn't).

Comment: No way. The displayed image is much larger! Besides, the question asks for TWO IMAGES. (I **really** wonder how totally wrong and failing answers like this one are upvoted instead  of being downvoted!)

Answer (score 14):

If you are looking to show images at their actual size, so the actual pixel size is the same for both images in subplots, you probably just want to use the options `sharex` and `sharey` in the subplot definition

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(15, 7), dpi=80, sharex=True, sharey=True)
ax[1].imshow(image1, cmap='gray')
ax[0].imshow(image2, cmap='gray')
```

results in:

[image]

Where the second image is 1/2 size of the first one.

Comment: How do you add a title for each plot ?

Comment: Take eaxh ax[n] object and use the title function

Comment: How do you adjust the axes of the small picture to match its smaller size ?

Comment: What do you mean? The trick here uses sharex and sharey to share the axes so the images show at the right scale. That is, same axes = real pixel size.

Comment: The other trick is to call the `imshow` with the larger picture _last_, as that will define the width/height of both plots. Right?

Comment: This is not only definitely the **correct** answer but also an elegant one. It should get the most upvotes! But it is a common phenomenon in this place that **wrong** answers get the most upvotes. This is a mystery to me ...

Comment: Where do you base the figure size on (15, 7)? Shouldn't you consult the image dimensions? And then, why do you set a dpi of 80 and not 100, which makes for smaller figure size (if you consult image dimensions)?

Answer (score 13):

Adapting Joseph's answer here: Apparently the default dpi changed to 100, so to be safe in the future you can directly access the dpi from the rcParams as

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def display_image_in_actual_size(im_path):

    dpi = mpl.rcParams['figure.dpi']
    im_data = plt.imread(im_path)
    height, width, depth = im_data.shape

    # What size does the figure need to be in inches to fit the image?
    figsize = width / float(dpi), height / float(dpi)

    # Create a figure of the right size with one axes that takes up the full figure
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
    ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])

    # Hide spines, ticks, etc.
    ax.axis('off')

    # Display the image.
    ax.imshow(im_data, cmap='gray')

    plt.show()

display_image_in_actual_size("./your_image.jpg")
```

Comment: this is useful but could be shorter by just saying that the default dpi can be accessed with `dpi = matplotlib.rcParams['figure.dpi']`

Comment: True, but I mainly wanted to accomodate copy-pasters here to have a ready-made function. I agree it's bloated.

Comment: To define plt add `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt` at the top.

Comment: You adapted the wrong answer! That answer is not what the question asks.

Comment: That answer is what people are looking for when they land here through Google, which is how most people use stackoverflow. It's how I found this thread 6 years ago, 3 years after the question was asked. And apparently people found it useful, otherwise they wouldn't upvote. I suggest to accept that this is how people use this site instead of berating them. Congrats on providing the correct answer to the original question. You could've left it at that instead of going into the comments of other answers.

Answer (score 0):

One must consult the image dimensions and use the larger ones in order to create an apprropriate figure size. So, here we go:

```
dpi = 100

(h1,w1),(h2,w2) = originalImage.shape[:2],outputImage.shape[:2]
w,h = max(w1,w2),max(h1,h2) # Get largest width and largest height
figsize = (2*(w/dpi),h/dpi) # Set the figure size acc/ly

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=figsize, dpi=dpi, sharex=True, sharey=True)
ax[0].imshow(originalImage, cmap='gray')
ax[1].imshow(outputImage, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```