# Matplotlib - unable to save image in same resolution as original image

Tags: python, matplotlib, resolution

I am unable to save the image without the white borders and at the initial resolution (`1037x627`)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import pyplot, lines
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
x=[0,0,0,0,0]
y=[0,0,0,0,0]
a=10**1.3*15
inc=25
b=np.cos(np.radians(inc))*a
x[0],y[0]=516.667,313.021
x[1],y[1]=x[0]-a,y[0]
x[2],y[2]=x[0]+a,y[0]
x[3],y[3]=x[0],y[0]+b
x[4],y[4]=x[0],y[0]-b
for pa in range(0,10,5):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    img=mpimg.imread('IC342.png')
    imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
    x[1],y[1]=x[0]-a/2*np.cos(np.radians(pa)),y[0]-a/2*np.sin(np.radians(pa))
    x[2],y[2]=x[0]+a/2*np.cos(np.radians(pa)),y[0]+a/2*np.sin(np.radians(pa))
    x[3],y[3]=x[0]+b/2*np.cos(np.radians(pa+90)),y[0]+b/2*np.sin(np.radians(pa+90))
    x[4],y[4]=x[0]-b/2*np.cos(np.radians(pa+90)),y[0]-b/2*np.sin(np.radians(pa+90))
    ell = Ellipse(xy=[516.667,313.021], width=a, height=b, angle=pa, edgecolor='b',lw=4, alpha=0.5, facecolor='none')
    name='plt'+str(pa)+'.png'
    leg='PA='+str(pa)
    #ax.text(10, 10, leg, fontsize=15,color='white')
    ax.add_artist(ell)
    xn=[x[1],x[2],x[0]]
    yn=[y[1],y[2],y[0]]
    xnw=[x[3],x[4],x[0]]
    ynw=[y[3],y[4],y[0]]
    line = lines.Line2D(xn, yn, linestyle='-.',lw=5., color='r', alpha=0.4)
    line1 = lines.Line2D(xnw, ynw, linestyle='-.',lw=5., color='g', alpha=0.4)
    ax.add_line(line)
    ax.add_line(line1)
    plt.axis('off')
    fig.savefig(name, transparent=True, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0,dpi=150 )
```

initial image

[image: Initial img]

Result

[image: Resulting img]

Also I need the white text `PA=something` to be on the image without changing the resolution. From what I understand adding another figure like text might automatically change the resolution.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There are two factors at play here:

1. An `Axes` doesn't take up the entire `Figure` by default
2. In `matplotlib`, the `Figure`'s size is fixed, and the contents are stretched/squeezed/interpolated to fit the figure.  You want the `Figure`'s size to be defined by its contents.

To do what you want to do, there are three steps:

1. Create a figure based on the size of the image and a set DPI
2. Add a subplot/axes that takes up the entire figure
3. Save the figure with the DPI you used to calculate figure's size

Let's use a random Hubble image from Nasa http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/hubble_friday_12102015.jpg.  It's a 1280x1216 pixel image.

Here's a heavily commented example to walk you through it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# On-screen, things will be displayed at 80dpi regardless of what we set here
# This is effectively the dpi for the saved figure. We need to specify it,
# otherwise `savefig` will pick a default dpi based on your local configuration
dpi = 80

im_data = plt.imread('hubble_friday_12102015.jpg')
height, width, nbands = im_data.shape

# What size does the figure need to be in inches to fit the image?
figsize = width / float(dpi), height / float(dpi)

# Create a figure of the right size with one axes that takes up the full figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])

# Hide spines, ticks, etc.
ax.axis('off')

# Display the image.
ax.imshow(im_data, interpolation='nearest')

# Add something...
ax.annotate('Look at This!', xy=(590, 650), xytext=(500, 500),
            color='cyan', size=24, ha='right',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='fancy', fc='cyan', ec='none'))

# Ensure we're displaying with square pixels and the right extent.
# This is optional if you haven't called `plot` or anything else that might
# change the limits/aspect.  We don't need this step in this case.
ax.set(xlim=[-0.5, width - 0.5], ylim=[height - 0.5, -0.5], aspect=1)

fig.savefig('test.jpg', dpi=dpi, transparent=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

The saved `test.jpg` will be exactly 1280x1216 pixels.  Of course, because we're using a lossy compressed format for both input and output, you won't get a perfect pixel match due to compression artifacts.  If you used lossless input and output formats you should, though.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much!!! 

The explanation is just what I needed, it's not enough to just fix the problem, I really want to know what to avoid in the future. I've never used annotations, but just plain text, this is super useful and I can't be any more grateful!

Comment: @Tigs - Happy to help!

Comment: They said here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53816322/5057078 that it changed from 80dpi to 100dpi, so use `dpi = matplotlib.rcParams['figure.dpi']` instead of fixed number.