# Matplotlib output image quality

Tags: python, matplotlib

After converting an png-image into a numpy array and back into an png-image the quality is reduced. If you click the second image, you can see it full size. I think the problem is that no anti aliasing or other filters are activated when the converted image is viewed.

Before conversion:

[image]

After conversion:

[image]

I tried:

```
plt.imshow(img2, cmap = 'gray')
plt.plot(aa = True)
plt.show()
```

to activate anti aliasing but it seems to change nothing. Is there a way to make the second image as pretty as the first again?

Comment: There are 2 parameters for plots, which should also work for images. You should look at: `figsize` and `dpi`.

Comment: I don't know why but matplotlib reduces image resolution from 704x490 to 562x394. I can `plt.savefig('file.png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi =125 )` which yields an image of 703x493 resolution. That being good enough, is there a way to just keep my image resolution during conversion?

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov 1. Your image have dpi 96, that will be enough. 2. To save image resolution, hide ticks etc. check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34769840/5510499).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I found the simplest way to do this.

```
img1 = plt.imread(impath1, format = 'int32')
plt.imsave('test.png', img1, cmap = 'gray')
```

Produces the exact same image.