# Matplotlib shows black & white image as gray

Tags: python, matplotlib, edge-detection, canny-operator

I have a simple code that loads RGB image, converts it to grayscale and then runs Canny edge detector algorithm. The returned image contains only 0 and 255 values, and yet when showing the image using matplotlib it shows the image as grayscale (and not black and white).

How can I fix this?

My code -

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

in_img = cv2.imread('colored_image.jpeg')
gray_in_img = cv2.cvtColor(in_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray_in_img, 100, 155)
fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 1)
ax.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(in_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 2)
ax.imshow(gray_in_img, cmap='gray')
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 3)
ax.imshow(edges, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

The output figure is:

[image: RGB image, grayscale image, and edges image]

Zooming in the last image we can see that in contains variety of gray intensities instead of black and white only:

[image]

whereas I'd like the last image to be a black and white image, such as:

[image]

When I've debugged the code, I've checked that the values of `edges` are indeed **only** `0` and `255`.

The original RGB image:

[image]

Comment: @john-hen When I added `ax.imshow([[255, 0], [0, 255]], cmap='gray')` I've gotten 4 squares - white, black, black and white as expected.

Comment: Adjust the image size of the subplots and remove padding, which will more clearly show the edges, can be done with [Displaying different images with actual size in matplotlib subplot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28816046/7758804) and [Removing white space around a saved image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11837979/7758804), which doesn't require Tkinter. [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wsHY.png) and [Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6TXf.jpg). Essentially there isn't an issue, and making the image larger and removing the white boarder already have answers. So this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The `edges` image is black and white only:

```
import numpy as np

np.unique(edges)
#array([  0, 255], dtype=uint8)
```

When you zoom in on the interactive backend, you'll see that the edges are indeed black and white only.

By default, [`imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) uses `'antialiased'` interpolation which leads to some gray values for small scale images. You can use `'none'` or  `'nearest'` instead to prevent this:

```
ax.imshow(edges, cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
```

When you save the image to a compressed format (e.g. `png`) you'll also see some gray values in the saved image due to compression. You can prevent this by using a lossless compression or no compression, e.g. save as `tif` or as `png` with `pil_kwargs={'compress_level': 0}`.

---

**Update as per discussion in comments below:**
To see the full exact image with all details in pure black and white you need to scale your `edges` image so that 1 image pixel = 1 display pixel (you can use `tkinter` to [get your screen's dpi setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60747161/3944322)):

```
import tkinter
dpi = tkinter.Tk().winfo_fpixels('1i')

fig,ax = plt.subplots(dpi=dpi)
plt.axis('off')                                              # no ticks/tick labels
fig.subplots_adjust(0,0,1,1)                                 # no margins
fig.set_size_inches(edges.shape[1]/dpi, edges.shape[0]/dpi)  # 1 dot = 1 pixel
ax.imshow(edges, cmap='gray')
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWIMW.png) (to be viewed at 100 % zoom of your web browser)

Comment: Using `interpolation='nearest'`, I get the following: https://ibb.co/JQQxZJV, which is OK for the black&white issue, however it seems like the figure isn't true to the original - the edges are much fewer. I understand that using `np.unique` I can be sure that the image contains only `0` and `255`, however I don't understand why can't I view the image as the image I've added in the post (the one before the last).

Comment: If you show all 3 images side by side, the displayed image is just too small to have 1 image pixel = 1 display pixel, therefore you need interpolation (antialiasing) for a pleasant visual impression or - if you switch it off - you'll loose some details. If you show your third image large enough (or zoom in) you'll get something like the last but one image in your post.

Comment: you can easily verify this effect by opening the last but one image in your post in a new tab (firefox: right click on image -> open image in new tab): at 100 % it'll be crisp black and with, as soon as you zoom in or out a bit (say 110 or 90 %) the bright white lines turn gray.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting the `interpolation` keyword argument in the `ax.imshow()` method to `"none"`, and enlarging the subplots with the `figsize` keyword argument to show more details:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

in_img = cv2.imread('colored_image.png')
gray_in_img = cv2.cvtColor(in_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray_in_img, 100, 155)
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(16, 5))

ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 1)
ax.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(in_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 2)
ax.imshow(gray_in_img, cmap='gray')
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 3)
fig.tight_layout()
ax.imshow(edges, cmap='gray', interpolation="none")
plt.show()
```

Output *(the third image might still seem gray, but that's the anti aliasing from your browser; click to see the image in large)*:

[image]

Note the `fig.tight_layout()` line I added to have the subplots a bit larger.